# Custom Roles on join with enmap

Tags: discord.js

I’ve tried to add code to allow people to customise which role people get when they join a server which can be set on a per server basis however I cannot seem set get it working. The greeting channel, the greeting and the DM are all working. It is only the role adding. If you could point me in the right direction then that would be very helpful.

```
client.settings = new Enmap({
  name: "settings",
  fetchAll: false,
  autoFetch: true,
  cloneLevel: 'deep'
});
// Just setting up a default configuration object here, to have somethign to insert.
const defaultSettings = {
  prefix: "!",
  modLogChannel: "mod-log",
  modRole: "Moderator",
  adminRole: "Administrator",
  welcomeChannel: "chat",
  welcomeMessage: "Welcome to the server, {{user}} ",
  welcomeDMMessage: "text",
  rolesOnJoin: "Basic"
}

client.on("guildDelete", guild => {
  // When the bot leaves or is kicked, delete settings to prevent stale entries.
  client.settings.delete(guild.id);
});


client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
client.settings.ensure(member.guild.id, defaultSettings);
let roleAdd = client.settings.get(member.guild.id, "rolesOnJoin");
let welcomeMessage = client.settings.get(member.guild.id, "welcomeMessage");
let welcomeDMMessage = client.settings.get(member.guild.id, "welcomeDMMessage");
let role = member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name == roleAdd);
  welcomeMessage = welcomeMessage.replace("{{user}}", member.user.tag)
  member.guild.channels
    .find("name", client.settings.get(member.guild.id, "welcomeChannel"))
    .send(welcomeMessage, {files: ["https://cdn.glitch.com/ecc1aef4-3247-42a1-9361-cfc56e9c5ba1%2F75AC6C9B-3E71-4F25-B8CF-47050B4B8F21.jpeg"]})
    .catch(console.error);
  member.send(welcomeDMMessage);
  member.addRole(role);
});
```

Comment: What is the output when you log the `role` variable? Are you also certain that the server has the role name?

Comment: @Steamgamer what do you mean by the output? Also, I am certain that this server has this role and that the bot has all the needed permissions.

Comment: Please `console.log(role)` when you define the variable `role`, as well as logging `client.settings.get(member.guild.id, 'rolesOnJoin');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addRole()` needs the role ID (or the Role as an object), you can still find it via it's name with

```
let role = guild.roles.find(role => role.name == roleAdd)
member.addRole(role);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the problem is that `addRole()` expects either a `Role` object or a role ID:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleResolvable

`"Basic"` is neither.

If all you have is the role name, you need to find it by that name in the `guild.roles` Collection.